# GROUP BY clause in MySQL groups records with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

MySQL `GROUP BY` clause groups records even when they have different values.

However I would like it to as with DB2 SQL so that if records not contain exactly the same information they are not grouped.

---

Currently in MySQL for:

***id  Name***

*A    Amanda*

*A    Ana*

the `Group by id` would return 1 record randomly (unless aggregation clauses used of course)

However in DB2 SQL the same `Group by id` would not group those: returning 2 records and never doing such a thing as picking randomly one of the values when grouping without using aggregation functions.

Comment: Yes because you are grouping by id , it will return a random name and most probably first one always. Maybe you want the result to be grouped by id, name

Comment: The moral of the story here is don't use `GROUP BY` without including all of the selected non-aggregate fields.

Comment: You can, however, group by multiple elements. If not, I think your best bet would be to leave out mysql's group by and apply a where criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, however I often need to combine non-aggregate and aggregate fields and currently duplicate records are erased creating an operational risk for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `id` is a bad name for a column that is not the primary key of a table.  But that is not relevant to your question.

This query:

```
select id, name
from t
group by id;
```

returns an error in almost any database other than MySQL.  The problem is that `name` is not in the `group by` and is not the argument of an aggregation function.  The failure is ANSI-standard behavior, not honored by MySQL.

A typical way to write the query is:

```
select id, max(name)
from t
group by id;
```

This should work in all databases (assuming `name` is not some obscure type where `max()` doesn't work).

Or, if you want each name, then:

```
select id, name
from t
group by id, name;
```

or the simpler:

```
select distinct id, name
from t;
```

In MySQL, you can get the ANSI standard behavior by setting [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) for the database/session.  MySQL will then return an error, as DB2 does in this case.

The most recent versions of MySQL have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set by default.

Comment: That looks similar to what I found. Maybe the reason is that I only have reading permissions into the database or that I am using HeidiSQL client but I am not managing to change ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY value...

Comment: "MySQL will then return an error, as DB2 does in this case." that's actually not right (at least for my DB2 database). In my case it simply does not group those records.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an automated way to do this but using

```
GROUP BY id, name
```

Would give you the solution you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Group by in mysql will group the records according to the set fields. Think of it as: It gets one and the others will not show up. It has uses, for example, to count how many times that ID is repeated on the table:

```
select count(id), id from table group by id
```

You can, however, to achieve your purpose, group by multiple fields, something among the lines of:

```
select * from table group by id, name
```